# Storing historical data in oracle

Tags: oracle

[I have create a table T1 with columns NAME & CAL.

```
 CREATE TABLE T1 (NAME VARCHAR2(1), CAL TIMESTAMP(3);

 INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('A', TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-02-04 12:00:00.000000000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));

 INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('B', TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-02-04 12:00:00.000000000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));

 INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('C', TO_TIMESTAMP('2017-02-04 12:00:00.000000000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('D', TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-04 12:00:00.000000000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('E', TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-02-04 12:00:00.000000000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('F', TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-02-04 12:00:00.000000000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('G', TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-02-04 12:00:00.000000000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));
```

The above data gives CAL column with PM...In order to change the CAL column with AM ..I have written a query like

```
 UPDATE T1
 SET CAL = TRUNC(CAL);
 COMMIT;
```

After this query, data is updated with AM in CAL column.

I want to store historical data of table T1 into other table T2 in such a way that I need to store the historical data of 4 years from now. This is the query I have written but data is not getting populated

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (NAME VARCHAR2(1), CAL TIMESTAMP(3);
 
INSERT INTO T2
(
  NAME,
  CAL
 )
  SELECT NAME, CAL FROM T1 WHERE TO_CHAR(CAL) >= TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,-48), 'YYYY');

 SELECT * FROM T2;
```

I was not getting expected result as shown in the pic.

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7fyA.png)

Comment: okay...neglect the AM and PM...Can you help me with WHERE clause..Y its not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to @Old Programmer:

On your original insert, your column did not "have"  AM or PM. It had the internal binary representation of the timestamp, as mentioned by @Old Programmer.  That internal format is *always* a binary representation of:

- 4-digit year
- 2-digit month
- 2-digit day of month
- hour of day, in a 24-hour clock
- minutes of the hour
- seconds of the minute
- partial seconds, down to the nanosecond.

But look at the data of your actual INSERT.

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-02-04 12:00:00.000000000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
```

So you gave an hour of the day of '12', and had a format mask of "HH24", indicating that the provided string was expressing time on a 24-hour clock. Thus an hour of '12' is interpreted as noon.  Or '12 PM'.

The "PM" was the result of your query client doing an implicit to_char, with a format mask to give AM or PM.

Then your 'truncate' set the time component of the timestamp to all zeros -- midnight.  Thus, your query client then reported '12 AM'.

Read more about internal representation of date/timestamp vs. displayed string representations, [here](https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/nls_date_format/).

I think you probably *do* want to include a trunc().  If you don't, and your run your query for the 'last 4 years' at, say, 13:32 (1:32 PM) on Feb 17, 2021, it will only go back to 13:32 on Feb 17, 2017.  Whereas, if you include trunc(), you will effectively ignore the time component and get everything for Feb 17, 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Date and timestamp types are not stored with a format. the formatting is applied by the client, so no need for calls to TO_CHAR. Try this:

```
SELECT NAME, CAL 
FROM T1 
WHERE CAL >= ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,-48);
```

Comment: What if I need a previous 4 year records from now i.e from 1st Jan 2018 till now..Do I need to add anything like TRUNC?

Comment: no need to trunc.  Trunc on a date/timestamp just sets the hour:min:seconds to zero.